# R data.table: how to read correctly

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have csv file with data:

```
filename <- "myfile.csv"
```

Looks like this:

```
A,"B","C","D"
1,"2.4","5","6"
```

I am using `data.table` library to read this file:

```
table <- fread(filename, header = F, sep = ",", quote = "", stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Then I get:

```
1: "A      ""B""       ""C""      ""D"""       
2: "1    ""2.4""   ""5""      ""6"""
```

I don't understand why I got so much `"`, and how ro read my data correctly.

P.S. Without `quote` I get warning:

```
Found and resolved improper quoting in first 100 rows. If the fields are not quoted (e.g. field separator does not appear within any field), try quote="" to avoid this warning.
```

And the data is:

```
1: A,""B"       "C"      "D""       
2: 1,""2.4"   "5"      "6""
```

So it also doesn't work correctly - I need to have 4 columns, but I get 3.

Maybe I have to use another function to read my data?

The original data is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MFr8IUyVdwj98HESiFC_2sWwabDF4HqB/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: You don't need the `quote` argument and neither the other arguments.

Comment: @Jaap, edited my question, unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: What version of data.table are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce on data.table `1.13.0`.

Comment: @user438383, I have `1.13.0`. Maybe something is wrong with original file? Added link on it in my question.

Comment: Could you try with `quote = "\""`?

Comment: @Jaap, get the same error as without `quote`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how all these quotation marks got in there but as far as I can see they are unnecessary. Then one (albeit slightly dirty) solution is removing them before passing the data to `fread()`:

```
fread(text = gsub('"', '', readLines('test_data_01.csv'), fixed = TRUE))

         V1      V2       V3      V4       V5
1: -2. 5935    II 2   0.4984 ST 123E -2.154 4
2:  -0.2888 ST 123E   1.5636 ST 123E   0.1053
3: -0.828 6 ST 123E -0.9 791  HP 129 -0. 4989
4:  -0. 322 ST 123E  -0.3013  HP 129  -0.4032
5:  -0.5588 ST 123E   1.2694  HP 129  0.703 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the quote argument.

```
a = fread('A, "B", "C", "D"
1, "2.4", "5", "6"', header=F)

> a
   V1  V2 V3 V4
1:  A   B  C  D
2:  1 2.4  5  6
```

This works the same as if reading from a file.

From the data.table manual:

> By default ("""), if a field starts with a double quote, fread
> handles embedded quotes robustly as explained under Details. If it
> fails, then another attempt is made to read the field as is, i.e., as
> if quotes are disabled.

EDIT: with original data;

```
a = fread('V1,"V2","V3","V4","V5"
-2. 5935,"II 2","0.4984","ST 123E","-2.154 4"
-0.2888,"ST 123E","1.5636","ST 123E","0.1053"
-0.828 6,"ST 123E","-0.9 791","HP 129","-0. 4989"
-0. 322,"ST 123E","-0.3013","HP 129","-0.4032"
-0.5588,"ST 123E","1.2694","HP 129","0.703 9"')
```

```
> a
         V1      V2       V3      V4       V5
1: -2. 5935    II 2   0.4984 ST 123E -2.154 4
2:  -0.2888 ST 123E   1.5636 ST 123E   0.1053
3: -0.828 6 ST 123E -0.9 791  HP 129 -0. 4989
4:  -0. 322 ST 123E  -0.3013  HP 129  -0.4032
5:  -0.5588 ST 123E   1.2694  HP 129  0.703 9
```

Comment: I downloaded your original data and it worked fine for me (see edit). I'm not sure what's causing this - hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: You think I need to copy my data from file and add `'`, or I can do something without copying?